# Apache as Proxy replace the html code/tags/text

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, proxy, html, sed

I configured my Apache server as a proxy server. I added some filters to my `proxy.conf` file to change the text (HTML source code) of the websites.

Example code:

```
ExtFilterDefine foodo mode=output intype=text/html
cmd="/bin/sed -r 's/foo/newfoo/g'" 
SetOutputFilter foodo
```

I have enabled also every possible mods for that. (`mod_proxy`, `mod_proxy_html`, ...)

After I used also `mod_sed` to change some text but still I have no positive solution.

```
<Directory "/var/www/docs/sed"> 
    AddOutputFilter Sed html 
    OutputSed "s/monday/MON/g" 
    OutputSed "s/sunday/SUN/g" 
</Directory>
```

Here is my proxy.conf:

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

Do anyone have any idea for this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>You should be able to use [mod_substitute](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_substitute.html). In your proxy config, add:</strike>

```
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
Substitute "s/foo/bar/ni"
```

---

I got it working with the following config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName su-test.int.mtak.nl

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost Off
        ProxyPass       / http://mtak.nl/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://mtak.nl/
        RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding

        FilterDeclare CUSTOMFILTER
        FilterProvider CUSTOMFILTER SUBSTITUTE resp=Content-Type $*
        FilterProvider CUSTOMFILTER SUBSTITUTE resp=Content-Type $/html

        <Location />
                FilterChain CUSTOMFILTER
                Substitute "s|foo|bar|ni"
        </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

The line `RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding` is to make sure the webserver doesn't send a gzipped response, which Apache would be unable to substitute the contents of.

Comment: Yep i tried that also today! `sudo a2enmod substitute` and then `<Location /> AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html 
Substitute s/foo/bar/ni 
</Location>` and then i restarted my apache server! Then when i visited the website from the client side and look up the source code "foo" is still there.

Comment: And also my  proxy.conf file looks like that: `ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On
<Proxy *>
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from all
</Proxy>`

Comment: @xmux I've updated my post with a config that is tested and works for me.

Comment: Thanks! but then this one is the 000-default.conf file and i want still a proxy server actually. And i am using apache 2.4, does it make any difference?

Comment: It is a piece of the total Apache config. If you put this anywhere in your Apache config (or in `/etc/(apache2|httpd)/sites-enabled`), it will make virtualhost su-test.int.mtak.nl a proxy.

Comment: You were totaly right about this "RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding"  after that i just updated my proxy.conf with <Location /> AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html  Substitute s/foo/bar/ni  </Location> and it just worked! Thanks a lot! if you want, you can change the answer to a normal substitute example.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I had a feeling that gzip was causing the issue so I tried AddOutputFilterByType INFLATE to fix this. But although now response wasn't gzipped still substitute was not working. I tried you technique and it worked.

Comment: Getting an error on the first FilterProvider line: "FilterProvider takes three arguments, filter-name provider-name match-expression"

Answer (score 2):

For Apache >= 2.4 the `FilterProvider` syntax was changed. I was able to get the following to work:

```
FilterProvider CUSTOMFILTER SUBSTITUTE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^text/html|"
```